# React Native run-ios --device not working after upgrading xcode command line tools

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode-command-line-tools

The question is pretty self explanatory: I just updated the XCode Command Line Tools and now the `npx react-native run-ios --device` is giving this error:

```
npx react-native run-ios --device
info Found Xcode workspace "LsRecordApp.xcworkspace"
error No iOS devices connected.
```

While if I run

```
xcrun xctrace list devices
== Devices ==
MacBook Pro di Alessandro (4DE942D7-9E58-5917-AED1-F0B770F513E7)
iPhone di Alessandro (15.2) (00008020-000459C40CD1002E)
```

Any idea?

```
npx react-native info
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: macOS 11.6.2
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Memory: 1.91 GB / 32.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.13.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.15 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.3.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2021.09.27.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.0.1, iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4 Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4
    Xcode: 13.1/13A1030d - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.9.1 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
    react-native: 0.66.0 => 0.66.0
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```